# How do I get izpack installer to correctly restrict a fileset based on OS architecture

Tags: java, installation, izpack

I have a simple installer using no custom panels and one pack to install.

The pack has two fileset elements and each file set element is restricted by the <os> element.

```
<packs>
    <pack name="My Application Pack" preselected="yes" required="yes">
        <description/>
        <fileset dir="@{basedir}/x86_64" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH/">
            <os arch="x86_64"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="@{basedir}/x86" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH/" >
            <os arch="x86"/>
        </fileset>
    </pack>
</packs>
```

My installer builds and runs successfully, but when it's done, it has ignored my <os> restriction, and placed all the files from the x86_64 folder as well as the x86 folder into my $INSTALL_PATH.

I'm running on a 64 bit Windows 7 machine.

Can anyone tell me if I'm doing something wrong, or could this possibly be a bug in izpack?

OBTW... as a test, I changed the restriction to this...

```
<os arch="sparc"/>
```

... and it successfully did not install the files when I ran my installer on my Windows 7, 64 bit machine.  I'm not sure if that proves that this is some sort of izpack bug or not, but I thought it would be useful information.

Comment: I've figured out that I was unwittingly running a 32 bit JRE when double clicking my installer that I'm building to do the install of my software.  The answer below from sunbabaphu explains that a match of the beginning of the value will be valid.  This explains the false positive I was getting.  The false positive was actually on the arch=x86_64 setting since I was running a 32 bit JRE.  Rene Krell told me to use arch="amd64" instead of x86_64, and now when I run with a 64 bit JRE, the correct files get installed.  So, I'd like to add that the setting of <os arch="x86"/> is a bit misleading.

Comment: I think it's misleading, because the resolution of <os arch="x86"/> is happening against the JRE, and not the system architecture.  At least not with my Windows 7 machine.  I have multiple Java Runtimes on my system, and I was thinking that the double click of the installer I built would use the Java I specified with the Environment variable, JAVA_HOME.  It was not doing that.  I'm not sure what setting is making the double click of a jar file use one of the 32 bit versions of Java I have on my machine. Maybe a Registry setting???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The IzPack doc. page here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/IZPACK/OS+Restrictions)
gives an overview of using OS Restrictions. Also, within that page you'll find a link to ***A List of known OS names and architectures..*** [or click here.](http://lopica.sourceforge.net/os.html)

After a brief reading of the page @ 2nd-link-above, it seems that ***os arch=x86_64*** works for Linux family and, as such, it isn't listed for windows 64-bit.

At the end of that page you'll find a sample code to find out the values of **os.name, os.version and os.arch** specific to your system. you may use these values directly in

```
<os arch="XXX"/>
```

the page also mentions that

> Values that only match the beginning of os.name or os.arch are also valid (e.g. if you specify Windows and the os.name is Windows 98, for example, everything works out fine)

so there IS some flexibility in naming conventions.

also, once you get this working for your system, pls email your combination of os.name, version and arch to the email address mentioned in the above page so that they too can be listed.

Comment: This answer explains the reason I was getting a false positive for the arch="x86_64" setting.  I've learned that setting arch="amd64" is the way to go.  One of the current active developers, Rene Krell told me to use that value, and it worked. I've also learned that this value is quite misleading. The resolution of the value is based on what JRE you are using to run the installer, and not the OS system architecture.  When I use a 32bit JRE to run the installer, my x86 files get installed, when I use a 64bit JRE, my x86_64 files get installed. Is this the intended functionality?

Comment: Not directly related to this question but one important thing to take in account when you use the tag <os> is that all your files must exist.
For example you have <file> for family="windows" and another <file> for family="unix" platform. Even if you are packing for the windows platform, the file you declare for the unix platform must exist.